# OCZ agility 4 is not recognized by Toshiba SSD Tool

Tags: ssd, disk-utility, secure-erase

I have a working OCZ Agility 4 SSD as system drive. It is working.

I want to secure erase it and update its firmware (if available).
The problem is that **Toshiba/OCZ [SSD Utility](https://ssd.toshiba-memory.com/en-amer/download/ssd-utility) wont detect/recognize it**.
I did send an email to the support, but I didn't get an answer.

Is this SSD drive not supported? If so, which SSD Tool should I use?

Comment: It's an almost 18 year old product. It's likely that it's simply not supported as it isn't listed anymore on the website. There are plenty of tools and assuming your SSD supports an erase command you could simply trigger that use one of those. Otherwise there are also plenty of erasing tools. it's not really clear what your problem is. It seems odd to update the firmware of such an old drive and secure erase it at the same time.

Comment: @Seth Oh, I didn't realize that it was THAT old... Well, just want to secure erase it, can you point out a tool?

Comment: Not necessarily how old your specific drive is but that's when it was first listed on e.g. Amazon (AGT4-25SAT3-128G, May 2012). As I mentioned you'd first have to check the capabilities. Have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1284450/quickest-way-to-wipe-an-ssd-clean-of-all-its-partitions-for-repartitioning-in-li) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1102184/how-can-i-securely-wipe-an-ssd/1102202) for some options.